How to combine two equations?
I've participated in the German Math Olympiad a few days ago (this stage is alread over) and there's the following problem:
$$x^2 = 21 - 4 \cdot y$$
$$y^2 = 21 + 4 \cdot x$$
where all real solution to the equation are to be found.
Now my question is not about the solution, but a particular step I performed while trying to solve this problem.
What I did is to subtract (2) from (1), which resulted in the following equation:
$$ x^2 - y^2 = -4 \cdot (y + x)$$
As can be seen the summand 21 simply cancels out. The issue here's though, that a summand different from 21 would yield another solution to the equation.
Now my question is: Do I add both equations correctly? Or do I make any mistake

If equations (1) + (2) imply (3) , what can we say about the solution sets to (1)+(2), and to (3) ? Which is larger? Does one contain the other?

You have a system of two equations. It's OK to subtract one from another and get the third equation. However, you should still have a system of two equations as the result and you should not discard the original equations altogether. The resulting system can have the new equation and one of the originals.

Any solution to your simultaneous equations will also be a solution of their difference, but the reverse is not true.
For example, $(x,y)=(-3,3)$ is a solution of both $x^2 = 21 - 4  y$ and $y^2 = 21 + 4  x$ so you can be confident that it is also a solution of $x^2 - y^2 = -4  (y + x)$, and it is,
while $(x,y)=(0,4)$ being a solution of $x^2 - y^2 = -4  (y + x)$ should not give you confidence that it is a solution of either $x^2 = 21 - 4  y$ or $y^2 = 21 + 4  x$, and it is not.
But since any solution of both $x^2 = 21 - 4  y$ and $y^2 = 21 + 4  x$ is also a solution of $x^2 - y^2 = -4 (y + x)$, it is worth investigating that last equation, which suggests $x=y-4$ or $x=-y$.  Then

substituting  $x=y-4$ into $x^2 = 21 - 4y$ gives $y^2-16y+16=21-4y$ which you can solve for $y$ and thus for $x$
substituting  $x=-y$ into $x^2 = 21 - 4y$ gives $y^2=21-4y$ which you can solve for $y$ and thus for $x$

You may now be able to see that you could get different solutions in that last step (and a different number of real solutions) if you used, say, $12$ rather than $21$ in the original equations.
